# How Does Github Do pushState Without Hash Tags?

Tags: html, url, github, pushstate, history.js

I've been researching the best way to utilize HTML5's history api aka psuhState with a proper fallback for HTML4 browsers.

Github uses the history api for its tree browsing (the following link is just an example, not the library github uses):

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

What I can't figure out is how they handle this functionality for HTML4 browsers such as Firefox 3.5?

I've looked at, specifically, history.js (linked above) to handle this sort of thing. But it requires a hash # implementation for HTML4 browsers which I'd like to avoid.

If you visit Github and browse a directory tree using an HTML4 browser, it looks identical to an HTML5 browser (the url state, that is).

If I disable JavaScript in FF3.5, a URL which previously looked like this:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/tree/master/tests

now looks like this:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/tree/a32e91aa1fe5909a29abb690a37f6c129e98068e/tests

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GitHub uses http://pjax.heroku.com/

For browsers that don't support pushState it simply degrades to normal old boring full-page-load behaviour.

Comment: So for that fallback behavior, does that mean Github is physically creating those directories on the server? Or are they creating the directories on the fly somehow? I'm confused about how they operate the fallback technique?

Comment: Are they creating the folder structure on the server?

Comment: No, what's being displayed is just a rendering of what's contained in the repo.

Comment: this uses rails am i right? Anyone know of a less complicated solution?

Comment: Just either:
1) Build your pages out normally with every url being a normal server request. Then add JS and HTML5 pushstate to change urls dynamically with prefetched data. That way old browsers get love or 2) Build your app out in a JS app framework like backbone with HTML5 pushstate turned on and add in Nginx or Apache redirects to always serve the same index.html file no matter the request and have Backbone assemble on the fly. These are pretty much your only choices.

Comment: @Yahreen Just because you see the directories in the URL doesn't mean that they have that directory structure on the server. Github's backend code can parse different request URLs and serve the right file, so they do this programatically.

Answer (score 7):

[Responsive web design from the future](http://warpspire.com/talks/responsive/) is a 96 slide presentation from Kyle Neath, a designer that works at GitHub, that might help you.

> pushState. replaceState. Hashbangs. AJAX. PJAX. Beets. Bears.
>   Battlestar Galactica.
>
> Responsive web design is about a lot more than the size of your
>   screen. This talk is about about how GitHub handles links, the url
>   bar, partial page updates, and explains why I think the HTML5 history
>   API is the most important thing to happen to front end development
>   since Firebug.