# ajax and hash urls

Tags: javascript, ajax, hash, hyperlink

I have a webpage designed to reload data with ajax. All of my ajax works well but I now realize that I want to keep track of where you are on the page and also be able to link people to specific pages on the site.

Here is the site I am talking about:

www.stevenlebel.com

As you can see, the page is made up of a tv that loads new content into the screen. The videos page uses embedded Vimeo code, the music page uses Soundcloud and images use an Imugr gallery. The reason I built it this way was to allow my friend to update his page without my help.

So my question is, how do I add hash links to the URLS - I would also like to be able to link to a certain video, song or image on the page but am not sure whether this is possible using Vimeo/Soundcloud/Imgur.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks a lot,

katie

A bonus questions:  Does anyone know how to remove the .html so when I use hash links the page would say x/x/#whatever instead of x/x.html#whatever?

Comment: A hashtag is a means of flagging something for searching on Twitter, please don't confuse it with a fragment identifier. Also, please don't abuse fragment identifiers to track state in this way, [it causes lots of problems](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs). Even [Twitter is stopping using them](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html). Instead [use pushState](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560570/how-does-github-do-pushstate-without-hash-tags).

Comment: Thank you for your input Quentin. Does it matter if my site is really small? It certainly isn't twitter and only has 5 pages total and maybe at the most will have 100 pieces of media

Comment: What does being small have to do with not having to work properly?

Comment: because there is less to manage. a large site like twitter has a lot more data to manage. thanks quentin - i think i found an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, You need HTML5 History API. There are some cool cross browser APIs of it you can use, have a look here http://html5demos.com/history to how it works.

You will need these things to keep track where you are. I consider you are not refreshing the page and using Ajax.

history.pushState Event, push any data with it and will be appended to url after #

history.popstate Event, use back/ forward to pop data.

window.hashchange Event, if you copy the url and open it to another or share it to anywhere. you will be able to fetch data after # in url.

You can try these cross browser APIs of it.

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

Good Luck!

Comment: what happens if the user doesn't have html5

Comment: Anytime Katie, you can look at the above API links :)