# How to send a GET request with a specific query string to my page using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

[This code](http://jsbin.com/urodit/193/edit) toggles the color of an element whenever you click on it. But how can I send a **GET request** with **query string** `?toggle=True` on the first toggle and `?toggle=False` on the second one?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I tried that but I can't get the query string to appear: [demo](http://jsbin.com/urodit/197/edit)

Comment: Aside from not sending the False version (since you only use `get` in one of your two toggle functions) … that works.

Comment: Why should I use it in both when I can't even get the first one to work?

Comment: The first one **does** work. I can see the request being made in the net tab of my browser's developer tools.

Comment: Ow, I can see it appearing in Firebug, but not in the url of the page. Any idea why? If you post a seperate answer I can accept it as an answer to this question. Btw, srry. When you said *"...that works"* I thought you were being sarcastic lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ow, I can see it appearing in Firebug, but not in the url of the page. Any idea why?

Making a request and changing the URI in the address bar are two different things unless you cause the browser to load a completely new page.

If you want to do that, then you should forget about using client side JavaScript and move your logic server side and use a regular link.

In the server side logic, the value of the query string argument would be used to determine the `class` of the div (which is used to set the style) and the `href` of the link (i.e. if it has True or False in the query string).

If you want to avoid loading a new page, then you are looking at two separate steps.

The first one you already have (the changing of the style using JS).

The rest gets more complicated…

First you need server side logic so that True/False in the query string will set up the initial state of the page correctly. This will be the same as the logic described for the previous method.

Then you need to update the URI so that it matches the one that would load the page in the state you are altering the current page into. This is done using the [History API](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) (`pushState` and friends). There are more details on the subject on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560570/how-does-github-do-pushstate-without-hash-tags).

If you want to notify the server of the change, then you'll need to use `jQuery.get`, as well as updating the page and changing the URI in the address bar. To be efficient, you should probably add an additional query string argument (so you can tell if it from Ajax from that a normal page load) and have the server return a simple acknowledgement rather than the whole HTML document when it sees that argument.

Comment: Thanks! Could you just include [this code](http://jsbin.com/urodit/199/edit) in the beginning of your answer and say it is only visible from a development tool? Thats easier for pple to find the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's get method to do so or do it yourself in your toggle functions.

Answer (score -1):

A pragmatic yet pretty basic solution may be to use a local variable as a counter.. If the counter is even, send True, if odd, send False.

Increment counter on each click :)

Comment: Pointless though. The jQuery toggle functionality (that the code linked from the question is using) already lets you distinguish between the odd and even cases. This just duplicates that detection and is thus worthless.